Can I define and use a variable to use in systemd unit file itself?
Trying to avoid possible mistakes I'd like to define and use variables to be used withing the systemd unit file itself, i.e.: not for the command executed.
For example consider this (invalid) unit:
[Unit]
CONFIG=/etc/some_dir/%i.conf
AssertPathExists=$CONFIG
#...

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=$CONFIG
# ...

So I want to define variable CONFIG and use it for several unit directives.
Is that possible?

No, systemd units do not support this.
